# Template Toolkit week number and day

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I want to display the week number and the day with the date plugin in Template-toolkit. The output for today would be something like:

```
36 Monday
```

I got the week number with the following code:

```
[% USE date(format = '%W' ) %]
[% date.format %]
```

Still trying to figure out how to get the weekday.

Comment: It looks like you expect us to jump to your call and write the code for you, but Stack Overflow isn't like that. When you post a question here you are expected to have tried your very best to fix a coding problem and failed. Please show us what you have written and describe the obstacle that is preventing you from progressing

Comment: Did you look at the documentation on CPAN ? It is complete with a lot of examples.

Comment: @Borodin I have been looking at http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Date.html for how to do this.  I have also been searching on Google to find some examples. I have code for displaying today's date but that code is in no way relevant to my question.

Comment: The first sentence of the description of the Date plugin is: "The Date plugin provides an easy way to generate formatted time and date strings by delegating to the POSIX strftime() routine."  You can find strftime format info here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html

Comment: There isn't a "the week number"; there are several significantly different ways to count weeks.  strftime, and hence Template::Plugin::Date, usually supports three of them (%U, %V, and %W), but there are others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Date.html

> The Date plugin provides an easy way to generate formatted time and date strings by delegating to the POSIX strftime() routine.

From http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#strftime

> Consult your system's strftime() manpage for details about these and the other arguments.

From http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

> %A The full weekday name according to the current locale.

Comment: Thank you very much! [% USE date(format = '%A') gives the weekday!